# what do I do this happened

Tags: grub2

Ran into a problem:

[image: screenshot]

Please help me if you know what happened tell me how to fix it I'm on my phone right now.

Comment: You will have to give us more info that this, the image is barely readable. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Its a gnu grub priblem the kernel is terminated by no means and I think the one that got rid of my windows 10 for this  bullshit got a killswitch on it

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

Boot into the Ubuntu live CD for the version of Ubuntu that you have installed and run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).  Alternatively, you can [repair it from the terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) if you are that advanced.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/XXX
```

where XXX is the device of your Ubuntu install.

Comment: Dont have the live cd and dont have acces to terminal

Comment: Catch 22; you'll need a more advanced kernel than your grub prompt in order to repair your computer.  You could purchase an Ubuntu CD or live USB online if you have no other options.  They're inexpensive.